# HTML5 Input "Required"

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

This is my code:

```
  <label>Child's First Name</label>
    <input runat="server" ID="ChildFName" type="text" required="required"/>
```

so it has button where it will be submitted to my Database. But the issue is, even though it doesn't have anything on the textbox input, the button I have still works. The required validator message will show but only for a few seconds and it proceeds to place blank columns in my database.

I noticed that this only happens I place runat="server" in my form like so:

```
<form runat="server">
<---code here--->
</form>
```

Here is the HTML code for my button

```
<button runat="server" onserverclick="RegisterUser" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

What can I do to make sure that it will not allow my button to proceed if the textbox I have is blank?

Here is my code for the button:

```
 protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection konek = new SqlConnection(db))
        {
            konek.Open();
            SqlParameter childfname = new SqlParameter("@childfname", ChildFName.Value);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RegisterUser", konek);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(childfname);
            SqlDataReader dataread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dataread.Read())
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
            }

            konek.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `required = "required"` is optional. Only required is fine. Check one more thing that is you have `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @NishatLakhani I did that too. nothing changes.

Comment: @NishatLakhani i have <!DOCTYPE html> as well

Comment: Just remember, even if you make this work perfectly, it is client-side validation and you still need to ensure your server-side code checks for valid data before inserting. I can easily modify the DOM of your page and remove 'required' attributes.